# c++: understanding dynamic arrays

Tags: c++

I am trying to understang a dynamic array. In this case - an array of pointers.

This program is Ok to me - it is working, everything is fine.

What troubles me is how the array is organized in the heap.

Let us launch it, that will be our example:

```
pn 00456878
pn[0] 003AFB90
pn[1] 003AFB80
pn[2] 003AFB70
```

Will you be so kind as to help me understand three matters:

1) Why the address of pn[0] is higher than that of pn[2]? I seemed to have assigned pn[0] before pn[1] and pn[2]?

2) I allocated memory in the heap for 3 elements of sizeof(POINT). 
sizeof(POINT) = 8. 
003AFB70 + 8 = 3AFB78. Why the next element is 003AFB80?

3) I have formed an opinion that an array in the heap looks as follows:

> ```
> pn->pn[0]
>     pn[1]
>     pn[2]
> ```

pn is a base address. The address of pn[0] = base address + 0.
Judging from what I can see here we can conclude that there is a gap between a base address and the first element. Is it for some auxiliarry data or what is it for?

Thank you in advance.

My code is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct POINT 
{
    int x; 
    int y;
};

POINT ** pn;
POINT ** tmp;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int counter = 3;
    POINT p_tmp;
    cout << "sizeof(POINT): " << sizeof(POINT) << endl;
    pn = new POINT * [counter];

    POINT a = {0, 0};
    POINT b = {1, 1};
    POINT c = {2, 2};

    pn[0] = &a;
    pn[1] = &b;
    pn[2] = &c;
    cout << "pn "<< pn << endl;

    cout << "pn[0] "<< pn[0] << endl;
    cout << "pn[1] "<< pn[1] << endl;
    cout << "pn[2] "<< pn[2] << endl;
    cin.get();

    POINT m = * pn[0];
    POINT n = * pn[1];
    POINT k = * pn[2];

    cout << m.x << ","<<m.y<< endl;
    cout << n.x << ","<<n.y<< endl;
    cout << k.x << ","<<k.y<< endl;
    cin.get();

    tmp = new POINT * [counter];
    memcpy(tmp, pn, (counter  * sizeof(POINT)));
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        cout << "tmp[" << i << "] "<< tmp[i] << endl;
    }
    cin.get();
    delete[] pn;
    pn = tmp;

    m = * pn[0];
    n = * pn[1];
    k = * pn[2];

    cout << m.x << ","<<m.y<< endl;
    cout << n.x << ","<<n.y<< endl;
    cout << k.x << ","<<k.y<< endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not printing the address of `pn[0]`. You are printing its value. To get the address, use `&pn[0]`.

Comment: The confusion stems from you using an array of pointers, printing the actual pointers instead of the addresses of the pointers.

Comment: For bonus points, @Pepperwork, what is the type of `pn`? What about `pn[0]`? It looks like this is where you are getting confused.

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion arises from the fact that your array contains `POINT*`s and not `POINT`s.

> Why the address of pn[0] is higher than that of pn[2]? I seemed to have assigned pn[0] before pn[1] and pn[2]?

It's not the *address* of `pn[0]` that you are printing, it's its *value*. The *address* of `pn[0]` is denoted by `&pn[0]`.

```
POINT a = {0, 0};
POINT b = {1, 1};
POINT c = {2, 2};

pn[0] = &a;
pn[1] = &b;
pn[2] = &c;
```

Here you put in `pn` the addresses of `a`, `b` and `c`, which are `POINTS` you declared on the **stack**. The stack grows from upper addresses to lower addresses, therefore `&a` > `&b` > `&c`.

> I allocated memory in the heap for 3 elements of sizeof(POINT). sizeof(POINT) = 8. 003AFB70 + 8 = 3AFB78. Why the next element is 003AFB80?

No, you allocated memory in the heap for 3 elements of `sizeof(POINT*)` (pointer to `POINT`, which happen to also be 8 bytes). You allocated an array of three pointers *on the heap*, but the pointees are *on the stack*.

In the end, your array looks like this:

```
(some address) pn-> (00456878) pn[0]-> (003AFB90) a
                    (00456880) pn[1]-> (003AFB80) b
                    (00456888) pn[2]-> (003AFB70) c
```

The *pointer* `pn` is static memory, but *points* to 3 pointers *on the heap* that point back to 3 elements *on the stack*.

---

If you wanted to have everything on the heap, you'd do it like this:

```
Point **pn = new POINT*[counter];

for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
    pn[i] = new POINT;
```

In this layout, the *pointer* `pn` is in static memory, but *points* to 3 pointers *on the heap* that point to 3 elements *on the heap*.

Comment: the heap is organized similarly?

Comment: @Pepperwork Similarly to stack? No. It's a very different beast. Take a look a [Doug Lea's malloc](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html).

Comment: There, I added a few details. I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm trying to digest all this information. I seem to be completely ignorant of what the things really are like.

Comment: @NolwennLeGuen, well, a local pointer is really kept on the stack. But I read that a dynamic pointer is kept on the heap. Maybe this could help me? Anyway, how could I alter my code so that the picture should be integral (that is all pointers point at the heap, no gaps between elements).

Comment: Whoops, yes, my mistake, `pn` is on the stack, I updated my schema, and added some more info.

Comment: @NolwennLeGuen, POINT ** pn is global here. This means that it is kept in static memory. I've tried what you suggested. But failed.